# Is it possible to replace nested loops on different collections with Stream API

Tags: java, java-stream, nested-loops

I was wondering if it's possible to rewrite nested `for` loops using [java.utils.stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) in **Java 8**?

Here is a sample data type I'm working with:

```
class Folder {
  private final String name;
  private final Integer itemCound;

  Folder(String name, Integer itemCount) {
    this.name = name;
    this.itemCount = itemCount;
  }

  public String getName() { return this.name; }
  public Integer getItemCount() { return this.itemCount; }
}
```

Here's code in action:

```
List<Folder> oldFolders = new ArrayList<>();
List<Folder> newFolders = new ArrayList<>();

// Fill folder collections with sample data...
oldFolders.add(new Folder("folder1", 2));
oldFolders.add(new Folder("folder2", 4));
newFolders.add(new Folder("folder1", 0));
newFolders.add(new Folder("folder2", 100));

// This part should be rewrited using streams
for (Folder newFolder : newFolders) {
  for (Folder oldFolder : oldFolders) {
    if (newFolder.getName().equals(oldFolder.getName()) 
        && !newFolder.getItemCount().equals(oldFolder.getItemCount())) {
      // do stuff...    
    }
  }
}
```

P.S: I've seen other questions on **SO**, but all of them had 1 collection or a collection with it's own nested collection instead of two different collections like in my example.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not in any way that would *improve* the code.

Comment: "_//This part should be rewrited using streams_" I don't really agree, this is actually simple, readable and efficient. Now what you can do is change the `if` to use a `filtre` but this can be done just using `stream` on `oldFolders`.

Comment: @AxelH, my concern was, maybe there is more efficient way to rewrite this part (because two `for` loops will iterate more times that are actually needed - in cases when folder names aren't equal maybe we could skip iteration).

Comment: In that case, you need to be more specific on the requirement, is there more than one occurrence possible, is the list sorted, how big can it be. This is currently a O(n2) but with sorted list this could be done in O(n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That not much of an improvement to be fair unless if you can parallelize the first iteration (commented in this example)

```
List<String> oldList = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>();

oldList
    //.stream()
    //.parallel() 
    .forEach(s1 ->
    newList
        .stream()
        .filter(s2 -> s1.equals(s2)) //could become a parameter Predicate
        .forEach(System.out::println) //could become a parameter Consumer
);
```

Replacing the `if` with a `filter` and his `Predicate` then executing a method on it.

This would give a solution that can be dynamic providing different `Predicate` and `Consumer` to the `filter` and `forEach` method. That would be the only reason to work on this conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you can:

```
newFolders.forEach((newFolder) -> {
    oldFolders.forEach((oldFolder) -> {
        if (newFolder.getName().equals(oldFolder.getName()) 
        && !newFolder.getItemCount().equals(oldFolder.getItemCount())) {
           // do stuff...    
        }
     })
  })
```

EDIT: But as @Kayaman mentions in the comments below this is not necessarily better than just using nested for loops.

This is a good read for when you should and shouldn't consider using streams:

[In Java, what are the advantages of streams over loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44180101/in-java-what-are-the-advantages-of-streams-over-loops)

Comment: Note that this is essentially the same as the for loops in the question, except now you've got some lambdas in the mix. This is in no way **better**, and due to the additional lambdas it's actually a bit worse if you get down to the bytecode.

Comment: Thanks for the article, @Plog

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
newFolders.stream().filter(newFolder -> 
            oldFolders
                    .stream()
                    .anyMatch(oldFolder-> 
                            newFolder.getName().equals(oldFolder.getName()) &&
                                    !newFolder.getItemCount().equals(oldFolder.getItemCount())
                    )).forEach(folder -> {
                        //dostuff
    });
```