# Java streams and their advantages

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm new to stream programming and I would want to know what are the benefits of using streams instead of the classical methods in Java. It seems just like a different way of computing the same thing. I want to know if I should start learning how to use them or just continue using the same approach.

Comment: I would look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44180101/in-java-what-are-the-advantages-of-streams-over-loops)

Comment: Sometimes using a Stream is much simpler and cleaner than using a loop, sometimes a loop is better, but much of the time it is a matter of taste and it's good to have options.