# Where is implementation of toList()?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a question for the following code in [the best answer on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44180101/in-java-what-are-the-advantages-of-streams-over-loops):

```java
return people
     .filter( p -> p.age() < 19)
     .collect(toList());
```

Where is the implementation of `toList()`? `java.util.stream.Collectors.toList()`? I don't understand why `toList()` can be here. How does it works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`toList()` means [`Collectors.toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList()) with `java.util.stream.Collectors.toList` is being statically imported.

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
```

[`Stream#collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.stream.Collector)) expects a [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collector.html)

```
<R, A> R collect(Collector<? super T, A, R> collector);
```

and [`Collectors.toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList()) returns a [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collector.html)

```
public static <T> Collector<T, ?, List<T>> toList() { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a static method in the Collectors interface - see here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--