# Reducing ArrayList<MyClass> using MyClass attributes

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a class, `MyClass`, like this:

```
public class MyClass() {
  String name;
  Long amount;

  public MyClass() {
    // No arguments constructor
  }

  public Long getAmount() {
    return this.amount;
  }
}
```

If I want to get the sum of `amount` in an ArrayList of MyClass items, usually I would do this:

```
// assuming ArrayList<MyClass> myClassList
Long amount = 0L;
for (MyClass x : myClassList) {
  amount += x.getAmount();
}
```

But now to improve performance, I am trying to use `Stream.reduce()`. My approach:

```
// assuming ArrayList<MyClass> myClassList
// reduce all MyClass items to a single MyClass item that holds the total amount
Long amount = myClassList.stream().reduce(new MyClass(), 
(curr, next) -> {
  Long currAmount = curr.getAmount() != null ? curr.getAmount() : 0L;  // subtotal
  Long nextAmount = next.getAmount() != null ? next.getAmount() : 0L;  // next value to add
  curr.setAmount(currAmount + nextAmount);  // next subtotal
  return curr;
}).getAmount();
```

Is there a better way to do so? And how would the reduction be affected if `currAmount` or `nextAmount` is null?

Comment: Changing to a stream for this case is unlikely to improve performance. In that case it is better to just stick with the simpler and more readable variant with the for-each loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But now to improve performance, I am trying to use Stream.reduce()

[Stream does not improve performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658322/java-8-performance-of-streams-vs-collections), the main idea using stream is [benefit from functional programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44180101/in-java-what-are-the-advantages-of-streams-over-loops). If you want to improve performance, please do proper [benchmarking](https://antoniogoncalves.org/2015/01/15/micro-benchmarking-with-jmh-measure-dont-guess/).
Anyway, you can simplify the stream as below.

```java
Long amount = myClassList.stream()
                  .mapToLong(m -> m.getAmount() == null ? 0L : m.getAmount()).sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use reduce as like below:

```
Long amount = myClassList.stream()
            .filter(m -> m.getAmount() != null)
            .mapToLong(Product::getAmount)
            .reduce(0, Long::sum);
```