# Best Concise Way Using Java for Weighed Selection of An Index

Tags: java, list, java-stream

If we have a list of doubles as `List<Double> weights` we want to select an index of it where the cumulative sum till that index is greater than a random number. If the loop reaches to the end of the list and still the condition is not met we return the last index inevitably. We can use a simple loop and do the check for that but I want to see if there are better, more Java, ways which use stream, reduce, parallel stream, or etc. that comes to your mind.

```java
final double[] cSum = { 0 };
double rnd = random.nextDouble();
int ind = weights.stream().reduce(weight -> {
    cSum[0] += weight;

    if (rnd < cSum[0]) {
        return weights.indexOf(weight);
    }
}).get();
```

Comment: have u tried anything ? or POC code ?

Comment: I tried reduce but not sure how to use the if condition to check the the condition i mentioned inside it. this is what i have which is wrong and not complete. ```final double[] cSum = {0};
double rnd = random.nextDouble();
int ind = weights.stream().reduce(weight -> {
                cSum[0] += weight;
                if (rnd < cSum[0])
                    return weights.indexOf(weight);
            }).get();```

Comment: i feel using classic for each loop with incremented value is good choice for performance also

Comment: Streams aren't good for problems that process only part of a list.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the problems where a `for` loop would be more readable over streams.

```
int sum = 0;
int random = 4;
int[] arr = {3, 5, 6, 1};
int index = arr.length - 1;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    sum += arr[i];
    if (sum > random) {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
} 

System.out.println(index);
```

---

> I want to see if there are better, more Java, ways which use stream, reduce, parallel stream, or etc. that comes to your mind.

A `for` loop through an `array` is extremely lightweight both in terms of heap and CPU usage. If raw speed and memory thriftiness is a priority, using a stream is worse. The decision whether to use Streams or not should not be driven by performance consideration, but rather by readability. When it really comes to performance, there are other considerations.

Streams also follow lazy evaluation: Computation on the source data is only performed when the terminal operation is initiated, and source elements are consumed only as needed. All intermediate operations are lazy, so they’re not executed until a result of a processing is actually needed.

What you want is intermediate results at every index to compare it with the random number, personally, I'd prefer writing a normal `for` loop in this case.

---

Parallel Streams **do not guarantee** the order of traversal, so it'd be the wrong implementation choice here.

---

[You can read more about for loops vs streams here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44180101/in-java-what-are-the-advantages-of-streams-over-loops)